# Solving partial differential equation of more than 2 independent variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations, jacobian

If we have a function f(x,y,z) and have this equation

$af_{x}+bf_{y}+cf_{z} = 0$

I have 2 questions :How do we transform the variables x,y,z to ξ,n,k to solve the differential equation?

I mean $1)\frac{dx}{ds}  = a , 2)\frac{dy}{ds} = b , 3)\frac{dz}{ds} = c$  if we had 2 variables we would divide $\frac{1)}{2)}$ to find a relationship between $dx$ and $dy$ in order to find the characteristic equation, now what do we do ?

When we find the Jacobian to see if the transformation from x,y,z to ξ,n,k is valid in case of my example now do we need to find the determinant of a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: Hello. How can we help?

Comment: Can you answer the question?

Comment: You have $$\frac{dx}{a} = \frac{dy}{b} = \frac{dz}{c} = \frac{df}{0}$$ The final ratio implies one characteristic curve is given by $f = C_{3} = g(C_{1}, C_{2})$. Can you find two more characteristic curves that determine $C_{1}, C_{2}$ from the first three ratios?